Restored snapshot, seeing zero rows in the tables after restart or repair
I’m encountering an issue during snapshot restoration in Cassandra.
Scenario:

Backup taken from: 3-node cluster (A)
Restored on: 3-node cluster (B)

After successfully restoring the snapshot, the data size on the new cluster (B) was around 10 GB (same as backup size). However, when I either restart the Cassandra services or run nodetool repair, the data size reduces drastically (e.g., from 10 GB to 500 MB), and I’m seeing zero rows in the tables.
Has anyone experienced this before or have insights into why this might be happening? Any suggestions would be appreciated!
I tried with the below steps.

Create snapshot backup.
Shutdown Cassandra.
Recreate keyspace and tables.
Copy snapshots to relevant data directories.
Start Cassandra.
nodetool repair


Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Your description is incomplete but I suspect that the destination cluster B does not have an identical configuration as the source cluster A.
When restoring using the "refresh method" (either with nodetool import or nodetool refresh), the destination node must have the same token range(s) as the corresponding source node otherwise the partitions in SSTables you restored will not necessarily belong to the destination node.
Only the partitions which the node owns will be kept. The rest of the partitions the node doesn't own will be dropped.
I've previously documented how to clone data to another cluster using the refresh method on DBA Stack Exchange. But if the clusters don't have identical configuration, you'll need to clone the snapshots to another cluster using sstableloader. Cheers!

Thanks for your update.

Thanks for your updates.
In my case both cluster A and cluster B have identical configuration (same node, same RF etc.)
I am not aware of the same token but I did the same steps in past with no issue.
1.Create snapshot backup from cluster A.
2.Recreate keyspace and tables in cluster B.
3.Shutdown Cassandra.
4.Copy snapshots backup to all relevant tables directories in cluster B.
5.Start Cassandra.
6.nodetool repair.

Hi , Regarding the same token range. Could you please update me if I am wrong.


From the old cluster, retrieve the list of tokens associated with each node’s IP:
nodetool ring | grep -w <ip_address_of_node> | awk '{print $NF ","}' | xargs


Add the list of tokens we obtained in the previous step to the initial_token parameter in cassandra.yaml file for each node in the new cluster so that new cluster also will have the same token rang.



@DineshChandra I'd like to make a friendly request and ask that you create a new post. If we keep answering questions in the comments, it will be a never-ending thread. Cheers!
